# php unlink returns file not found

Tags: php, permissions

So, I have a script in

> /var/www/vhosts/Domain/SubDomain/Script.php

that writes images to

> /var/www/vhosts/Domain/wwwDomain/PhotoLocation/

and this works fine.

However, when I run this script:

> /var/www/vhosts/Domain/SubDomain/Script_to_Delete_Photo.php

which uses the 'unlink' command

> unlink ("/var/www/vhosts/Domain/wwwDomain/PhotoLocation/Image.jpg")

I get the error

> "PHP Warning"  "No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/vhosts/Domain/SubDomain/Script_to_Delete_Photo.php"

I thought that since I could WRITE the file fon a different subdomain, I could Delete from the other subdomain as well.

am I missing something?

Do I need to set Permissions somewhere else, or set a path differently?  I specifically call the File by Absolute Path, and I can verify that the file exists there.

Answer (score 0):

All looks fine. Some suggestions:

- files are case sensitive
- check if the folder `Photolocation` has write permission (it usually will for you can write to the location)
- close the **handle** after you've created the file. If the handle is still open, delete is not possible
- check with `file_exists()` just to make sure the file does exist
- did you create the `file` or a `shortcut`?
- when creating the file, do not suppress possible errors. It might be a header problem in the created file itself. Check your error-files for clues.